# avoid repeate scenario loop function in cucumber,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am very new to cucumber. This is my scenario

```
Scenario: Create new custom subscription
Given I logged in as an Account Admin
And I visit Manage subscription page
When I click create new subscription1
When I click create new subscription2
When I click create new subscription3
When I click create new subscription4
When I click create new subscription5
When I click create new subscription6
```

You can see here

```
When I click create new subscription
```

This last line is repeated six times. I would like to create a loop for this last two line. Is there any possible in Cucumber capybara?

Thanks for you advise.

Comment: Try to avoid being specific about UI details in the scenarios. 'When I click on...' woud be better as 'When I make a new subscription', with the actual details of what is clicked hidden in the step definition. That way, if you alter the process, the step definition changes, but the scenario still reads the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible in scenario but it can add in step-function

```
When /^I click create new subscription$/ do
  s = 1
  6.times do
    click_on('Create New Subscription')
    fill_in "subscription_name", :with => "Custom Subscription#{s}"
    click_on('Save')
    click_on('Back')
    s +=1
  end
end
```

Other wise we can you FactoryGirl

Comment: How do i achieve this in C# - Spec flow - Cucumber ?